# Precision_score and accuracy_score showing value error

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm new to this machine learning and using this boston dataset for predictions. Everything except the result for precision_score and accuracy_score is working fine . This is what i have done :

```
import pandas as pd 
import sklearn 
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn import preprocessing,cross_validation, svm
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, f1_score, precision_score, recall_score, classification_report, confusion_matrix

boston = load_boston()
df = pd.DataFrame(boston.data)
df.columns= boston.feature_names
df['Price']= boston.target

X = np.array(df.drop(['Price'],axis=1), dtype=np.float64)
X = preprocessing.scale(X)

y = np.array(df['Price'], dtype=np.float64)

print (len(X[:,6:7]),len(y))

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=cross_validation.train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.30)

clf =LinearRegression()
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_predict = clf.predict(X_test)

print(y_predict,len(y_predict))
print (accuracy_score(y_test, y_predict))
print(precision_score(y_test, y_predict,average = 'macro'))
```

Now i get the following error:

> File "LinearRegression.py", line 33, in
>
> ```
>  accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_predict)    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py",
> ```
>
> line 172, in accuracy_score
>
> ```
>  y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
> ```
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py",
>   line 89, in _check_targets
>
> ```
>  raise ValueError("{0} is not supported".format(y_type))
>
>  ValueError: continuous is not supported
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using a linear Regression model as

```
clf = LinearRegression()
```

which predicts continuous values. eg: 1.2, 1.3

Whereas `accuracy_score(y_test, y_predict)` expects boolean values. 1 or 0 (true or false) or categorical values like 1,2,3,4 etc.. Where the numbers act as categories.

That's why you are getting an error.

How to solve this?

Since you are trying to predict `Price` on boston data which is a continuous value. I recommend you change your error measure from accuracy to RMSE or [MSE](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error.html)

Replace:

```
print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_predict))
```

with:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
print(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_predict))
```

That will solve your problem.

Comment: but even when i change the classfier to Svm or RandomForestClassifier i get the same result . Do they predict in the same manner ?

Comment: @harshi RandomForestClassifier predicts 1's and 0's or categories like 0,1,2,3,4. Here you need discreet predictions for price which could be 1.2 or 0.24. They are continuous values.

Comment: @harshi read up more about the difference beyween classification problem and regression problem. It will help: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-main-difference-between-classification-problems-and-regression-problems-in-machine-learning

Comment: I figured out i can use ' clf.score(X_test, y_test)'  for accuracy .But calculating RMSE doesn't provide me with accuracy na . And how do i figure out the precision_score ?

Comment: @harshi precision_score is calculated for classification problems. This is a regression problem.

Comment: @harshi The clf.score() method will not get you accuracy. `LinearRegression` returns R-square coefficients in score. [See documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.score). Your concepts about classification and regression are not clear I think.

Comment: Ya . Got it .Thanks

Comment: See http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#regression-metrics for evaluating performance of regression estimators.